# How to enforce a minimum python poetry version

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am using python-poetry to manage dependencies in a python project. I want to enforce a minimum `poetry` version to avoid unnecessary changes in `poetry.lock` file in version control.

I tried updating it in `build-systems` section of `pyproject.toml` file but it works with lower versions as well.

Is there a way by which I can enforce minimum `poetry` version in a project?

Comment: I suggest following [this github issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3316)